# WooCommerce - Overriding billing state and post code on existing checkout fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I can't find the way to ovveride billing state and post code.

How can I edit the other parts of existing billing fields like billing state and post code?

This is what I have in the **`functions.php`** file in my child theme (I have included the code affecting the billing part):

```
    <?php
function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
  global $wpdb;
  $check_zone  = $wpdb->get_results("select area_name from brick_area where id='".$_SESSION['area']."'",ARRAY_A);

                if(!empty($check_zone)){
                    $check_zoneid = $check_zone['0'];
                }


    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_field_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Delivery Area'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Area'),
        'readonly'      =>'readonly',
        'default'       => $check_zoneid['area_name']
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_field_name' ));


    woocommerce_form_field( 'my_expected_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Expected Delivery Date'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter expected delivery date.'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_expected_date' ));

   /*woocommerce_form_field( 'my_expected_time', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Expected Delivery Time'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter expected delivery time.'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'my_expected_time' ));*/

    woocommerce_form_field( 'site_contact_name', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Site Contact Person Name'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter site contact person name.'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'site_contact_name' ));    

    woocommerce_form_field( 'site_contact_phone', array(
        'type'          => 'tel',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'required'      => true,
        'label'         => __('Site Contact Phone Number'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Enter site contact phone number.'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'site_contact_phone' ));       

}
        $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = $_SESSION['cn'];
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_address_fields' );
        function custom_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

            // we are changing here billing_state field to required
            $fields['billing']['billing_state']['required'] = true;

            return $address_fields;
        }
        /*$fields['billing']['my_field_name']['default'] = $check_zoneid['area_name'];
        $fields['billing']['my_field_name']['label'] = 'Area';*/

        return $fields;
        }
 ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: sure @LoicTheAztec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the complete way for billing state and billing post code override, keeping the billing selector with options.

Here is the code the fully functional and tested code:

1. Unsetting billing state and post code checkout fields

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'partial_unsetting_checkout_fields' );
function partial_unsetting_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);

     return $fields;
}
```

2. Reinserting custom billing state and post code checkout fields

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'art_override_default_address_fields' );
function art_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

  // @ for state
    $address_fields['billing_state']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['billing_state']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
    $address_fields['billing_state']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['billing_state']['label'] = __('State', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['billing_state']['placeholder'] = __('Enter state', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['billing_state']['default'] ='Choice 1';
    $address_fields['billing_state']['options'] = array(
        'option_1' => 'Choice 1',
        'option_2' => 'Choice 2',
        'option_3' => 'Choice 3'
    );

    // @ for postcode
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['type'] = 'text';
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['label'] = __('Postcode', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['billing_postcode']['placeholder'] = __('Enter your postcode', 'my_theme_slug');


    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Naturally this goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

Official reference: [WooThemes - Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)

---

> **Note concerning the `'class'` property**
>
> There is 2 ways to handle it:
>
> - The field is alone in one line (width 100%), you use: **`'form-row-wide'`**
> - There is 2 fields side by side on the same line, you use:
>
>   - **`'form-row-first'`** for the first field
>   - **`'form-row-last'`** for the second field

Answer (score 2):

```
//-------------------------- OVERRIDING BILLING STATE FIELD -------------------------------//

//Removing previous one by using unset
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);

     return $fields;
}
        

add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'art_override_default_address_fields' );

function art_override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    // @ for state
    $address_fields['Billing_State']['type'] = 'text';
    $address_fields['Billing_State']['class'] = array('form-row-wide');
    $address_fields['Billing_State']['required'] = true;
    $address_fields['Billing_State']['label'] = __('State', 'my_theme_slug');
    $address_fields['Billing_State']['placeholder'] = __('Enter state', 'my_theme_slug');

    return $address_fields;
}
```

Comment: In my case, I put is_logged_in so users without profile have to enter their address