# Displaying custom table values in WooCommerce checkout form

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I want display the external table value in WooCommerce checkout from company name field. We can create external table and insert some of company name.

When user signup our service in checkout field, customer should select the company name in a custom select options field. This values should be displayed from a custom database table.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are going to first unset the field type of company, and then to change it to a type 'select' (selector). Then we will maque a query to get all options key/values from your custom database table (Let's say is called 'wp_companies'):

***(ONLY FOR TESTING)*** NO database query here *(with 3 options for companies)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'set_custom_company_checkout_field' );
function set_custom_company_checkout_field( $address_fields ) {

    unset($fields['company']['type']);

    $address_fields['company']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['company']['options'] = array(
        'option_1' => 'Company 1',
        'option_2' => 'Company 2',
        'option_3' => 'Company 3'
    );
    // (optional) 
    // $address_fields['company']['default'] = 'Company 1';

    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Paste this code in function.php file located in your active child theme (or theme).*

This code is tested and works…

---

> **THE REAL CODE**: Making the query from database custom table ***(to be adapted)***:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'set_custom_company_checkout_field' );
function set_custom_company_checkout_field( $address_fields ) {

    // Unset company field type
    unset($fields['company']['type']);

    global $wpdb;
    $select_options = array();

    // @@@ you will need to replace names table and columns and adapt this !!!
    $query = "SELECT id, company FROM table";
    $companies_name  = $wpdb->get_results($query);

    // Storing object $company_name keys/values in $select_options array
    foreach ( $companies_name as $company_name ) 
    {
        $key = 'option_'. $company_name->ID;
        $value = $company_name->custom_column_value;
        $select_options[$key] = $value ;
    }

    $address_fields['company']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['company']['options'] = $select_options;
    // (optional) 
    // $address_fields['company']['default'] = $select_options['option_1'];

    return $address_fields;
}
```

*Paste this code in function.php file located in your active child theme (or theme).*

References:

- [WooThemes - Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)
- [WooCommerce - Overriding billing state and post code on existing checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395784/woocommerce-overriding-billing-state-and-post-code-on-existing-checkout-fields/)