# How to change Billing address field label in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

In my design i have non standard billing fields label and markup. For example "Town / City *" should be "Province *".

I have used WOO documentation, and filter `woocommerce_billing_fields`. And it works with class name, placeholder, create new fields. But I cant reach label changed.

```
$out_arr['billing_city']['class'][0] = 'form-row-first';
$out_arr['billing_city']['label'] = __('Province', 'woocommerce');
$out_arr['billing_postcode']['label'] = __('Zipcode', 'woocommerce');
```

and using `var_dump` of new `$out_arr` array it shows correct labels

```
["billing_city"]=>
array(4) {
["label"]=>
string(8) "Province"
["required"]=>
bool(true)
["class"]=>
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "form-row-first"
  [1]=>
  string(13) "address-field"
}
["autocomplete"]=>
string(14) "address-level2"
}
```

But i still have old labels in front-end. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**In specific cases** you need to use the **`woocommerce_default_address_fields`** filter. This filter is applied to all billing and shipping default fields: 
`'country'`, `'first_name'`, `'last_name'`, `'company'`, `'address_1'`, `'address_2'`, `'city'`, `'state'` or `'postcode'`.

Here we only use **`'city'`** and  **`'postcode'`** as in your code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'override_default_address_fields' );
function override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {

    // @ for city
    $address_fields['city']['class'] = array('form-row-first');
    $address_fields['city']['label'] = __('Province', 'woocommerce');

    // @ for postcode
    $address_fields['postcode']['label'] = __('Zipcode', 'woocommerce');

    return $address_fields;
}
```

**This is tested and working.**

*This code snippet goes on function.php file of your active child theme or theme*

References:

- [**Official** WooThemes - Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/)
- [WooCommerce - Overriding billing state and post code on existing checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38395784/woocommerce-overriding-billing-state-and-post-code-on-existing-checkout-fields/38411007#38411007)

Comment: @user6573193 Sorry but I just tested this on WooCommerce 3.0.9 and **it works too as before…**

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the OP question, but I faced a similar situation (we use "Department" instead of "Province") and found a solution that doesn't involve coding, which in my case makes things easier. It's the plugin **Booster for WooCommerce**.

It ads several other customization possibilities I have yet to try, but tweaking labels works just fine.

BTW, depending on your server settings it may cause an out-of-memory error upon activation, with WordPress returning a blank page. Temporarily increasing memory allocated to PHP allows it to complete activation.