# Override Woocommerce billing state field into a normal input field without losing the post data and needing to rewrire the whole post mechanism

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add auto fill to the billing state and city. The city is working perfectly because its just a normal text input. I have tried the following code from another stack overflow question, but no matter what I try, wordpress overwrites the field with a select option as soon as I use the id billing_state. The reason I am trying to use the ID is because wordpress does not register the post data from the name field, it seems to use the info based on the ID for some reason.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_form_field_text','delivery_checkout_address_fields', 10, 2 );
function delivery_checkout_address_fields( $field, $key){
    if ( ( $key == 'billing_postcode') ) {
        $field .= '<label for="billing_state">State</label><br><input id="billing_state" 
        name="billing_state" class="input-text"></input>';
    }
    return $field;
}
```

If there is a way to have a normal input field that submits instead of a select element that would be great, afterwards I will tackle the issue of the state code.

Alternatively, if I could somehow enter the value of the state select input using jquery, that would be even better, I also tried that but with no success.

Any help greatly appreciated

**Edit 1:**
I forgot to mention I am first unsetting the field of course, using

```
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
```

**Edit 2:**
Just to show my attempt with changing the type to text. State == Prefecture and it reverts to select.
[image]
[image]

**Edit 3:**
I was wrong not fixed -- I thought I had tried this earlier but in the end this fixed it, by changing the hook to the default address.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 
'override_default_address_fields' );
function override_default_address_fields( $address_fields ) {
    $address_fields['billing_state']['type'] = 'text';
    // ...
}
```

**Edit 4:**
I jumped the gun too soon, the following two images shows my issue is still not resolved, and the answers on the related question do not solve it for me.
[image]
And I think this is the cause, name ends up as billing_billing_state
[image]

Comment: I believe the following answer contains all the information needed to adjust the type of the field: [WooCommerce - Overriding billing state and post code on existing checkout fields](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38411007/11987538) - `$address_fields['billing_state']['type'] = 'text';`

Comment: Thank you for the post, I did actually try that, but wordpress overrides it back to a select box. I just tried again to make sure, but same issue. I ended up finding a work around by creating my own custom field, and then saving the the new value to $order->set_billing_state("state_code"); but its not the prettiest solution.

Comment: Take a look at the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408623/11987538) to that question, it contains everything you need, Tested and double tested

Comment: I just updated my debug image, so did you test it, I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: that doesn't seem like the code from the answers I already quoted, where is the `woocommerce_default_address_fields` filter hook used?

Comment: I dont have the code in front of me, I will check again tomorrow and let you know, thanks

Comment: thanks for your help, I should have caught on when the label was different in the debug to what was on the page. All working now